# What is this error

Tags: android-studio

> Error:
>
> Could not create parent directory for lock file
> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1-all.zip.lck

*I am Using:*  **Android studio 3.0.1 on Windows 10**

Comment: can you be more specify with your erorr

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that try to do **Invalidate Caches / Restart** or Sync.

OR

Try to set

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

then check "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" in Android Studio settings (Gradle tab).

Sync project.